# vs 2010: error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000342) "extern "C" int __stdcall

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010

The following code is taken from [here](http://simplesamples.info/Windows/EnumWindows.php). I removed all Windows NT part as I am working on Windows 7.

I copied this code and run in visual studio 2010 (New project-> VC++->CLR->CLR Console... ). But it is giving lots of unresolved extern 'c' errors as listed below the code.    What wrong I have committed?

```
#define STRICT  1 

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam) {
DWORD dwThreadId, dwProcessId;
HINSTANCE hInstance;
char String[255];
HANDLE hProcess;
if (!hWnd)
return TRUE;        // Not a window
if (!::IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
return TRUE;        // Not visible
if (!SendMessage(hWnd, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(String), (LPARAM)String))
return TRUE;        // No window title
hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);
dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwProcessId);
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcessId);
cout << hWnd << ' ' << dwProcessId << '\t' << String << '\t';
cout << "(None)\n";
CloseHandle(hProcess);
return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
return 0;
}
```

**This is giving following Errors(and other similar unresolved extern C errors)**

```
 1>wndowfind.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000342) "extern "C" int __stdcall       
 EnumWindows(int (__stdcall*)(struct HWND__ *,long),long)"     3
 (?EnumWindows@@$$J18YGHP6GHPAUHWND__@@J@ZJ@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl 
 main(int,char * * const,char * * const)" (?main@@$$HYAHHQAPAD0@Z)

 1>wndowfind.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000346) "extern "C" unsigned long  
 __stdcall GetWindowThreadProcessId(struct HWND__ *,unsigned long *)"    
 (?GetWindowThreadProcessId@@$$J18YGKPAUHWND__@@PAK@Z) referenced in function "int __stdcall 
 EnumWindowsProc(struct HWND__ *,long)" (?EnumWindowsProc@@$$FYGHPAUHWND__@@J@Z)

 1>wndowfind.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000347) "extern "C" long __stdcall 
 GetWindowLongW(struct HWND__ *,int)" (?GetWindowLongW@@$$J18YGJPAUHWND__@@H@Z) referenced in 
 function "int __stdcall EnumWindowsProc(struct HWND__ *,long)" 
 (?EnumWindowsProc@@$$FYGHPAUHWND__@@J@Z)

 1>wndowfind.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall  
 EnumWindows(int (__stdcall*)(struct HWND__ *,long),long)" 
 (?EnumWindows@@$$J18YGHP6GHPAUHWND__@@J@ZJ@Z) referenced in function "int __cdecl 
 main(int,char * * const,char * * const)" (?main@@$$HYAHHQAPAD0@Z)

 1>c:\users\afnan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\wndowfind\Debug\wndowfind.exe : fatal 
 error LNK1120: 10 unresolved externals
 1>
 1>Build FAILED.
```

**UPDATED**

By including the libraries (as suggested in the answers), I was able to run the program successfully. But I am not able to understand why only first character of string is printing not the complete one, as can be seen in the output:

```
00010060 2652   S       (None)
002502B2 5820   C       (None)
00090402 5160   w       (None)
00050392 5160   w       (None)
00060292 3520   F       (None)
000C02BA 3520   M       (None)
0001021A 3736   E       (None)
00040018 896    I       (None)
00010170 3580   A       (None)
0002003E 2684   D       (None)
00030316 4956   N       (None)
000202DE 3736   D       (None)
0001031E 2652   S       (None)
000100EA 2652   P       (None)
```

In the output above, S is actually "start", C is "console" etc I confirmed through spy++ tool. 
How can I print the complete string instead of just first character?

Comment: Your project is probably configured to build in Unicode, which means that you should use a wchar_t array rather than a char array.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CLR projects by default do not include the standard Windows libraries, such as `user32.lib`.

Edit your project properties, find the Linker Inputs option, and add `kernel32.lib user32.lib advapi32.lib` which are the usual libraries needed by Win32 code.

Comment: This was elusive. Thank you!